# My jquery ui accordion stops loading ajax pages after certain number of clicks

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

The problem I am facing is that after certain clicks on my console I first see this message "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience" and thereafter whenever I click on the mainMenu item, my default ajax page pertaining to that doesnt open and I also see this error in the console "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'". I am kind of lost in this problem and haven't figured out what is going on.

Here is my jquery part:-

```
 $(".accordion").accordion({collapsible:true, active:0, heightStyle: "content"});


    $("#protocolParameters").load("generalSystemStatus.html");


    $(document).on("click",".outerMenuItem",function(){

        var currentlyActive=$( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
        console.log("Current tab no. "+currentlyActive);

        if(currentlyActive===0){

            $("#protocolParameters").load("generalSystemStatus.html");


        }
        else if(currentlyActive===1){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("networkEthernet.html");


        }

        else if(currentlyActive===2){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("ntpDaemonStatus.html");

        }

        else if(currentlyActive===3){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("ptpMaster.html");

        }

        else if(currentlyActive===4){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("timingHardwareClockConfig.html");

        }

        else if(currentlyActive===5){              

            $("#protocolParameters").load("system.html");

        }

        else if(currentlyActive===6){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("adminAlarm.html");


        }

        else {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("/404.html .someError");

        }

    });

    $(".outerMenuItem").click(function(){
        if($(this).text()==="SYSTEM"){
           console.log("System Clicked");
            $("#protocolParameters").load("system.html");
        }
    });

    $(".innerMenuItem").click(function () {
        $(".innerMenuItem").removeClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
        $(this).addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
        if ($(this).text() === "General") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("generalSystemStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "Networks") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("networkStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "Timing") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("timingStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "GNSS") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("gpsStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "PTP") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("ptpStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "Alarms") {

            $("#protocolParameters").load("alarmStatus.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "Ethernet") {


            $("#protocolParameters").load("networkEthernet.html");

        }
        else if ($(this).text() === "SNMP") {


            $("#protocolParameters").load("networkSnmp.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "NTP Daemon Status"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("ntpDaemonStatus.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "PTP Master"){

            $("#protocolParameters").load("ptpMaster.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "PTP Slaves"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("ptpSlave.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text() === "Hardware Clock Configuration"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("timingHardwareClockConfig.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text() === "Holdover"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("timingHoldover.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text() === "System"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("system.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "Alarm"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("adminAlarm.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "Logging"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("adminLogging.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "Web Interface"){

            $("#protocolParameters").load("adminWebInterface.html");

        }

        else if($(this).text()=== "User Management"){


            $("#protocolParameters").load("adminUserManagement.html");

        }

        else{

            $("#protocolParameters").load("/404.html .someError");

        }

    });
```

Here is my html part:

```
 <div class="accordion">
    <h3 class="outerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusNormal"></div>STATUS</h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">General</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Networks</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Timing</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">GNSS</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">PTP</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Alarms</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="outerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusNormal"></div>NETWORK</h3>
    <ul class="submenu" id="networkSubmenu">
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">Ethernet</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">SNMP</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="outerMenuItem" ><div class="systemStatusRisk"></div>NTP</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">NTP Daemon Status</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="outerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusWarning"></div>PTP Management</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">PTP Master</a> </li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">PTP Slaves</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="outerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusNormal"></div>TIMING</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">Hardware Clock Configuration</a> </li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Holdover</a> </li>
    </ul>


    <h3 class="outerMenuItem innerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusNormal"></div>SYSTEM</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">System</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="outerMenuItem"><div class="systemStatusNormal"></div>ADMIN</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem innerMenuItemOnClick" href="#!">Alarm</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Logging</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Web Interface</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">User Management</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And here is the css :-

```
#sidebarElementDivPicture{
height:152px;
}

a{
   color: #3f3f4e;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-left:15px;
 }

a.innerMenuItem{
     color: #363545;
}

a.innerMenuItemOnClick{
    color:#eb5e13 !important;
}

.accordion .ui-icon{
     display:none;
 }

 .accordion .ui-accordion-header{
    height:30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width:200px;
  }

  .accordion .ui-accordion-header:hover{
     color:#eb5e13;
   }

   .accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-state-active{
      color:#eb5e13;
    }

    .accordion .ui-accordion-content {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 6;
       width:180px;
       color:#eb5e13;
     }

    .accordion .ui-accordion-header:active{
        color:#eb5e13;
      }

      #sidebar{
          float:left;
          padding-left:200px !important;
          padding-top: 22px;
       }
```

Comment: is there ajax code inside any of those html files?

Comment: Yes in few of them there is because I am using forms there and im submitting them using ajax as well.

Comment: Then one or more of those is set to `async: false` which is what the warning is about. It's always been a bad practice as it blocks the UI and is now being deprecated

Comment: Although I don't really know why it would stop being able to load what you've shown. Unless one of them is failing and locking browser. Not sure if accordion problem is related or not

Comment: I have checked all my files and infact I am not even using "async" property. So by default it should be true if not using it. Any other reason?

Comment: Thats what I am confused about. First I get the warning about depcrecation and straightaway after that i get that uncaught exception about accordion

Comment: possibly some accordion code in that file also. Something that is trying to set options on accordion that's not initalized, or calling `destroy` etc

Comment: Accordion is only in the code I have shared here. Do you think I should setActive option on all menu items before I try to grab it?

Comment: is accordion being replaced by any of the  `load()` calls? That might explain it. That error though is common with jQueryUI when you try doing something to a non intialized widget

Comment: No. The load calls are just loading other pages on a seperate div on the right. Accordion is just triggering those events. They are two seperate entities.

Comment: maybe there's another `.accordion` class in new html somewhere. Try using ID instead for main selector. Easy to check `alert($('.accordion').length)`

Comment: No. THere are no accordions in any other page other than the file i have shared here.

Comment: ok...but a stray class would do that also, check the length and switch to using ID

Comment: do u think changing my accordion from class to id should do the trick? Let me try that because i am having only one accordion anyway.

Comment: it would if there was one stray accordion class somewhere

Comment: Just switched from class to id. Still the same issue.

Comment: i really can't help more. Some reason it's not initialized when you do the menu click and try to get the active panel

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it fixed. The problem was not with the accordion code. The problem was the way in which I was calling script tags for jquery and jquery ui reference i.e

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

In few of my files that I was calling through AJAX, some of them had these scripts and as a result there was a switch in the Application context. I removed these tags from those files and make sure only my main page which has the accordion has these tags. It now works perfectly